# mySQLI Management

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Thanks to a poster here at SO, I started using MySQLI and prepared statements. However, there is one issue I'm not sure how to adapt from the way I used MySQL.

Before, I would open a connection to MySQL at the beginning of my main PHP script. Then any sub-script or class I used would automatically use the same connection just by calling the mysql_query() call.

Now, with MySQLI, it seems that if I want to use the connection in a class, I have to either pass the connection through the constructor or create a new MySQLI connection.

Is there a way to use a MySQLI connection the same way I was using the MySQL connection before?

take care,
lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the connection into the constructor is often the preferable method. That is called ["Dependency Injection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is useful for software testing.

However, if you would prefer not to use that method, you can simply access the connection globally inside any class method:

```
// MySQLi connection created in the global scope
$conn = new MySQLi(...);

class someClass {
  public someMethod() {
    // Call $conn with the global keyword
    global $conn;

    $conn->query(...);
  }
}
```

Better though, is to store `$conn` in a class property:

```
class someClass {
  // Connection property
  public $conn;

  public function __construct($conn) {
    $this->conn = $conn;
  }

  public someMethod() {
    $this->conn->query(...);
  }
}
```

If you are using MySQLi in a procedural context rather than object-oriented, you will need to supply the link parameter. There really isn't a way around it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.